# Android, Update ListView Adapter from another ListView Adapter

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

I have 2 Listviews side together (like android contact app the main list view is Names and the second one is alphabet) I need a method that when the user clicks on one object of second listview, the main list view update by the data that is coming from DataBase (exactly like the contact app again, but I must use this way, not using `SectionIndexer`).

finaly I need a way that when `onClick` event is calling in an `ArrayAdapter`, I be able to update another `ArrayAdapter` class.

Answer (score 0):

use `notifyDataSetChangedListener()` to update another listview on a click of other listview.

Comment: If both the listViews are in same activity, then you can directly access to another ListView within First ListView.
1.Make An Array of complete list ,  in sorted form alphabaticlly. OR YOu can use Doubly ArrayList of Size 26..Each one for Each Alphabet..
And when you click on 2nd ListView, you can update the first ListView by clearing the contents And setting a subArrayList to the ListView